# Terraform InvalidParameterCombination with AWS Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-rds

Having issues when trying to create an AWS RDS instance with terraform, I have gone through the documentation in AWS and Terraform and I just cannot see why this would be an invalid combination, I'm trying to create a free tier DB for testing:

```
module "rds" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/rds/aws"
  version = "6.3.0"
  identifier = "my-rds-instance"
  engine                = "sqlserver-se"
  engine_version        = "15.00.4335.1.v1" 
  instance_class        = "db.t3.micro"
  allocated_storage     = 20
  username              = "admin"
  password              = "*******"
  multi_az               = false
  vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_default_security_group.default-sg.id]
  subnet_ids            = [aws_subnet.eShop-subnet-2.id]  # Update with your subnet IDs
  major_engine_version = "15.00"  # Update with the correct value
  family           = "sqlserver-se-15.0"  # Update with the correct value
  license_model       = "license-included"
}
```

Error:

```
 Error: creating RDS DB Instance (my-rds-instance): InvalidParameterCombination: RDS does not support creating a DB instance with the following combination: DBInstanceClass=db.t3.micro, Engine=sqlserver-se, EngineVersion=15.00.4335.1.v1, LicenseModel=license-included. For supported combinations of instance class and database engine version, see the documentation.
│       status code: 400, request id: 989857f7-937c-4750-855d-b2347d6fa61d
│
│   with module.rds.module.db_instance.aws_db_instance.this[0],
│   on .terraform\modules\rds\modules\db_instance\main.tf line 29, in resource "aws_db_instance" "this":
│   29: resource "aws_db_instance" "this" {
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you looked through [DB instance class support for Microsoft SQL Server](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_SQLServer.html#SQLServer.Concepts.General.InstanceClasses) yet? I don't think (2019) `sqlserver-se` supports instance sizes as small as `db.t3.micro`, but `sqlserver-ex` does.